# Force.com IDE + EGit: Files tagged with "Dirty" are not actually dirty (aside from crlf differences)

Tags: force.com, eclipse, force.com-ide

Eclipse's Package Explorer is marking my file as Dirty.

[image]

But when I compare the file with the index (ie, **Right click > Compare With > Git Index**), I see no differences other than my line endings, which should have been dealt with. Note the line ending differences in my screenshot of the compare view. (left side is working file, right side is the index)

[image]

I've already configured Eclipse to handle whitespaces in the following areas:

- Checked the checkbox in **Windows > Preferences > Compare/Patch > Ignore white space** (tells Eclipse not to mark whitespace differences in the Compare view)
- Set `core.autocrlf=true` in **Windows > Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration > User Settings** and **Windows > Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration > System Settings** (tells EGit to ignore whitespaces properly, *I think*)

Now, the question is, why is my file still marked as dirty? Am I missing a step?

**Additional Info**

- Our Git repository has CRLF line endings.
- Salesforce has LF line endings.

Comment: This drives me absolutely insane, to say the least.

Comment: @sfdcfox It really makes it difficult to see which files have actually been modified. If it helps, I've recently discovered converting line delimiters (**File > Convert Line Delimiters To > Windows**). I run it at the `src` folder level just after refreshing from sfdc.

Comment: That's only half the problem. Tabs versus spaces, all sorts of whitespace issues because of different editors on different platforms. Even using the Developer Console results in a mess. I personally only pull one file at a time as I work on it, then commit in batches. I never pull from the src folder, which usually results in the entire tree being claimed as dirty.